# Re-show rightBarButtonItem that relies on mapbox mapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

My application is tab-based. On one tab is a map (which I am using Mapbox for.) When I click on this tab, it puts a trackingbarbutton item on the top right of the navigationcontroller top bar. When clicked, this button interacts with the mapView to show the user's location. The issue I am having is that when I go to another tab (besides the map), I need to remove the trackingbarbutton from the top right, as it does not apply to any of the other tabs.

Here is how the mapView and tracking bar button is initialized

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"example-map" ofType:@"mbtiles"];
  RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];

  //Initalize button in top-right
  self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[RMUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];
}
```

Here is where I hide the button

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Now normally, I would just re-initialize the button in a viewWillAppear(), but the issue is that I need to use the mapView object that was initialized in the viewDidLoad(). Does anyone have any ideas on how I can re-use that object or simply hide the rightBarButtonItem rather than deleting it completely? I would prefer not to re-initialized the mapView each time.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment, but this would operate the same way in MapKit as well, since the bar button item there works the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the `navigationItem` of your `UIViewController` instead of the `UITabBarController`. That way, the `rightBarButtonItem` should only show up when that view controller is shown and hide automatically when a new `UIViewController` shows its own `navigationItem`. Although I'm not 100% sure about this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  ...
  //Initalize button in top-right
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[RMUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];
}
```